# Product atributes in title of order (not in description)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order, variables

I have couple of variable products.
When someone order product, some product displey in new variation format (where order atributes are in title).
Image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10392998/29421924-9133df64-8344-11e7-8ee4-b2fd937afb72.png

– And other disply whit old variation format (where product atributes are in description)
Image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10392998/29421925-913bbcfc-8344-11e7-9d3d-54ab7e4a6962.png

How can i display all order in old variation format ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a little bit of code to be placed in functions.php. If you want you can use a plugin like WP-Designer to do that.

The WooCommerce filter 'woocommerce_product_variation_title' uses 4 arguments which are self-explanatory in the following piece of code which you can use in you functions.php. I tried it on my install and it works just fine.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title', 'wooc_product_variation_fix', 10,  4);

function wooc_product_variation_fix( $maybe_suffix, $product, $title_base, $title_suffix ) {

return $title_base;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply !!!
I'am really new to wordpress, i should add this i woocommerce functions.php or theme functions.php ?
On some orders i have old variation format and on some new variation format. Its look like old prodct have old format, and products that i add last have new format.
After add this all products will have old format ?  Thank You soo much and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can add them to theme's function.php

Comment: Thanks, i allredy add this: ` add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false' ); ` and i wait for new orders (this is not working for old orders ?), if i not work i will try whit code above,Thank You soo much